# Android App: Suspended from Google Play due to Deceptive Behavior policy violation

Tags: android, google-play-console, suspend

We have a screen were we are taking credit card details and send that details using our web API, with AES encryption.

Initial and second release was successfully accepted by google.

Later when we deploy new version then they suspended app due to this CC info.

We are not storing CC info on our DB, we will just make a subscription using stripe with that credentials.

We appeal already twice. But no success, any idea what to submit as verifiable document. i mean what is the content of the certificate.

[image]

Comment: Please explain about your app, because the details you mentioned are not related to the violation which is "Deceptive Behavior".
your app title, Logo, Screenshots, can use materials which fall into policy violation of Deceptive Behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a privacy policy to Google Play? I had a similar issue and it was fixed after I added that information to the privacy policy and contacted Google Play support. After 1-2 days, they accepted my app.

Comment: I will check this and let you know. thanks for the reply budd.

Comment: They continue sending same email - Examples of verifiable documentation (PDF) include, but not limited to: Business license, authorization contract, documents issued by financial institutions and et cetera.

Comment: Try to contact Google Play support. They will help you.